# Getting JSON info from API

Tags: react-native, axios, react-native-flatlist, apisauce

I'm using Axios(Apisauce) to connect API to React Native App;
this is the JSON file I'm trying to show in-app using FlatList :

```
{
  "data": {
    "sideMenu": {
      "url": "https://google.com",
      "icons": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "url": "https://google.com",
          "status": 1
        },
      ]
    },
  }
}
```

when I try to log it into the console, using `console.log(response.data)` returns all API info,  but using `console.log(response.data.data)` doesn't return the object I'm looking for!

I've tried `JSON.stringify()` or `toString()` but none of them seem to Work.

my Axios Code :

```
const getServices = () => {
  const service = "https://api.team-grp.ir/app/json/services2.json/";

  return client.get(service);
};
```

My Source Code:

```
  const ServiceInfo = async () => {
    await getServices()
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          setServicesData(response.data.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
        setServicesData([]);
      });
  };


useEffect(() => {
ServiceInfo();
});
```

Comment: Could you share your axios code?

Comment: please include your source code.

Comment: @DevLover Edited Main Question

Comment: @C.K Edited Main Question

Answer (score 1):

you should not use async/await with .then/.cache ...
this code is working for me:
(you can also see my sample code image at the bottom of this answer with a fake getService function, and you will see that logged response is correct)

```
const ServiceInfo = () => {
    getServices().then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          setServicesData(response.data.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
        setServicesData([]);
      });
  };


useEffect(() => {
   ServiceInfo();
}, []);
```

[image: here is my code sample image, with a fake getService function, you can see the correct log at the bottom of image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that

Answer (score 1):

```
const ServiceInfo = async () => {
    await getServices()
      .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
      })
      .then((response) => {
         setServicesData(response.data);
       })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
        setServicesData([]);
      });
  };
```

Try this